# Assigning random variables within turtle groups

Tags: netlogo

I have a dynamic number of groups of turtles (slider controlled, groups labeled with the variable group-id) which have an associated turtles-own variable (trait-1), I am attempting to randomly assign a different value to trait-1 for each group of turtles (group-id). At the moment each individual turtle has a randomly assigned trait-1 value which varies both within and among groups, but I want it to be the same for all individuals within each group, and only vary among groups. Any help would be great!

Side note, I am using a grouping variable instead of breeds as I couldn't figure out how to make the number of breeds dynamically controllable via a slider... not sure this is possible?

```
turtles-own [
  group-id ;grouping id, each group represents a species
  trait-1  ; a trait to be assigned a score from 1 - 10
 ]

to setup
clear-all
set-species
end

to set-species
let n_groups num_species  ;create n groups of turtles based on slider value (num_species)
foreach n-values n_groups [ ? ] [
create-turtles 3 [      ;create 3 indviduals in each group
  set group-id ?
  set color (group-id + 19) ; give each group a different color
  set  trait-1 1 + random 10 ]  ;set trait-1 ranging from 1 to 10
]
ask turtles [ set label group-id ] ; show group-id
ask turtles[  ; move turtles out of the center, not really important, just to help see the turtles. 
fd trait-1 
]
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just move where you set it outside of the turtle initialization:

```
  foreach n-values n_groups [ ? ] [
    let group-trait 1 + random 10  ;set it here
    create-turtles 3 [      ;create 3 indviduals in each group
      set group-id ?
      set trait-1 group-trait
      set color (group-id + 19) ; give each group a different color
      ;set  trait-1 1 + random 10 ]  ;don't set it here
    ] 
  ]
```